# change order content objects with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I need to change the order of the 'span' objects before the text in the elements 'a' using Jquery.

someone can help me?

```
<a href="#" class="has-submenu">
  Some text content  
  <span class="dropdown-menu-toggle"></span>
  <span class="sub-arrow"> > </span>
</a>
```

must to be :

```
<a href="#" class="has-submenu">
  <span class="dropdown-menu-toggle"></span>
  <span class="sub-arrow"> > </span>
  Some text content <-(This text must to be in the end)
</a>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why does this have to be done in jQuery versus just moving the HTML around?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.prependTo()` method to move elements to the beginning of a container element.

```js
$("#move").click(function() {
  $(".has-submenu span").prependTo($(".has-submenu"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="has-submenu">
  Some text content  
  <span class="dropdown-menu-toggle">toggle</span>
  <span class="sub-arrow"> > </span>
</a>
<br>
<button id="move">Move spans</button>
```

Comment: Thanks dear friend... this is i need